Column already exists when running local migration

I am running supabase locally
I have been using the Studio to create tables and their columns
I have been pushing the latest migrations up with supabase db push

When I run supabase migration up, I get this error
ERROR: column "story" of relation "initiatives" contains null values (SQLSTATE 23502)
At statement 3: alter table "public"."initiatives" add column "story" text not null

That error is coming from a migration that I thought was already applied.
